# How can I force the page number to the bottom center of the page for the first page of a paper

Tags: page-numbering

I am using the `sbl-paper` package for a seminar paper, and I need to have the page number on the first page of the body centered at the bottom of the page. I have looked through the other questions on stack exchange, but I cannot find a solution that works for my needs:

```
 \documentclass[]{turabian-researchpaper}

 \usepackage{sbl-paper}
 \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
 \usepackage{csquotes}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont{Times New Roman}

 \begin{document} 
 \institution{A Degree Granting Institution}
 \title{The Title of the Paper}
 \professor{The name of the professor}
 \course{Course number and name}
 \author{The Author}
 \date{April 26, 2018}
 \maketitle
 \setcounter{page}{1}
 \singlespacing   
 This is the first paragraph of the introduction.
 \end{document}

 % Local Variables:   
 % TeX-engine: xelatex    
 % End:
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This is probably coded in the class file or in  `sbl-paper`. Try `\thispagestyle{plain}`  just after `\maketitle`.

Comment: Awesome! I gave that a try and is seems to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sbl-paper` package uses the `fancyhdr` package to place the page number on the right side of the header of each page. The specific code used by `sbl-paper.sty`:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
```

The `turabian-researchpaper` document class, according to the [`turabian-formatting` documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/turabian-formatting), provides three page standard styles that can be used with the [`\pagestyle{}`](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_129.html) and [`\thispagestyle{}`](http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_131.html) commands: `empty`, `plain`, and `heading`. The `plain` page style "centres the page number in the footer."

As Bernard suggested above, placing "`\thispagestyle{plain}` just after `\maketitle`" should work.